# Internal server error when attempting to register user in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, internal-server-error

I have a database on AtlasDB cloud service. In my React application, I want my code to save the data from the form below to be saved in the database, however I get internal server error (500) when I make a post request. What could be the problem here? The code of the React component is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//state for form fields
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import { register } from "../actions/userActions";

const RegisterScreen = ({ location, history }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userRegister = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, userInfo } = userRegister;

  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split("=")[1] : "/";

  const goToLoginScreen = () => {
    history.goBack();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push(redirect);
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, redirect]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //dispatch register
    if(password !== confirmPassword){
        setMessage('Passwords do not match');
    } else {
        goToLoginScreen();
        dispatch(register(name, email, password));
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      {message && <Message variant="danger">{message}</Message>}
      {error && <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loader />}
      
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>

      <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Name </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="name"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="confirmPassword">
          <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            value={confirmPassword}
            onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
          Register
        </Button>
      </Form>

      <Row className="py-3">
        <Col>
          Have an account?{" "}
          <Link to={redirect ? `/login?redirect=${redirect}` : "/login"}>
            Login
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

It is very difficult to me to localize the error in code, whether it is a question of front-end or back-end. The user is not saved in the remote database.

Comment: Did you check in the browser dev tools like for the request data which you are sending ? . Also if you have access to the backend can you check whether you are able to receive the request with the post data correctly ?

Comment: An internal server error means that error occurred in the back end.  It's possible that the cause it on the front end, like if you are sending a malformed URL, but it's more likely that the back end is the problem.